# RSA, calculating value from lists

Tags: python, rsa, primes

I am writing my script to provide me with an RSA public and private key. I am trying to calculate the values of 'e' and 'd' where ed = 1mod64. I know the values will be e=5 and d=13. I have two lists of prime numbers up to 64, I want to multiply these lists together to calculate 'e' and 'd'. I am sure it will involve a while loop so that, while the value is not 65 keep going. I am struggling to write this code however as I am not sure how to get the lists to calculate not in parallel. Apologies if this has been asked but I have been going round in circles for quite some time, if it has been asked please just post the link to it and I shall remove this question.

Comment: By not in parallel, I mean by using the method I am thinking off the two lists will just multiply by the same numbers i.e. [2, 3, 5, 7] and [2, 3, 5, 7] will end up [4, 9, 25, 49], I would like it to go 2 multiplied by all the list, then 3 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of the `itertools` module, so here is an example using it.

Python:

```
import itertools
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7]
for p, q in itertools.combinations(primes,2):
    print ((p,q))
```

Output is:

```
(2, 3)
(2, 5)
(2, 7)
(3, 5)
(3, 7)
(5, 7)
```

Python:

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
for e, d in itertools.combinations(primes,2):
    if (e*d) % 64 == 1:
        print ((e,d))
```

Output:

```
(5,13)
```

Note that, in general, this is a terribly inefficient algorithm for finding modular inverses. You should instead use some version of the extended euclidean algorithm for anything larger than toy-sized parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1 = ed mod m is equivalent to saying that there exits an integer k such that 1 + k m = ed.
Since you are looking for a positive d < m, it can also be observed that k < e. Hence the following code should work

```
def invm(e,m):
   for k in range(e):
     if (k*m + 1) % e == 0:
        return (k*m+1)//e
```

This is reasonably efficient as long as e is small. Hence this even works for most real sized RSA keys, since most RSA keys use e=65537.